# Using builtin read with pipeline and here strings

Tags: bash, pipeline, herestring

I'm processing a package of pictures, from which "file" returns the following:

```
$ file pic.jpg
pic.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 96x96, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 231x288, frames 3
$ file pic.jpg | cut -d',' -f8 | tail -c+2
231x288
```

So I'm picking dimensions in two variables, using built-in "read", before proceeding with cropping.

But something eludes me. Why isn't this construct working...

```
$ ( file pic.jpg | cut -d',' -f8 | tail -c+2 | IFS=x read width height ; echo w:$width h:$height; )
w: h:
```

...while this construct is working?

```
$ ( IFS=x read width height <<< $(file pic.jpg | cut -d',' -f8 | tail -c+2) ; echo w:$width h:$height; )
w:231 h:288
```

To summarize, why can't I use a pipeline with built-in "read" in that situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, the commands in a pipeline are run in subshells (see the last paragraph of [Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines) in the manual). Any variables you declare in a subshell will disappear when the subshell exits.

You can use the `{ }` grouping construct to keep the `read` and the `echo` in the same subshell:

```
file pic.jpg | cut -d',' -f8 | tail -c+2 | { IFS=x read width height ; echo w:$width h:$height; }
```

This is why the here-string is useful: it runs the `read` command in the *current* shell, so the variables are available in the next command.

Comment: This nails the point. Just like I wrote `IFS=x` before `read`, `width` and `height` cannot be forwarded to the parent shell. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [identify](http://www.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick-7.0.0/script/identify.php) from ImageMagick and do

```
$ identify -format 'w=%[w]; h=%[h]' file.jpg
```

notice the use of `=` and `;` so you can do

```
$ eval $(identify -format 'w=%[w]; h=%[h]' file.jpg)
```

to set the variables in your shell

Comment: Thanks for the tip! My question focused on the use of `read` in that situation, but your answer is helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as you are using `bash`, there is an even easier method that only takes one line, no `eval`s, and  no `cut`s and no `tail`s:

```
read w h < <(identify -format "%w %h" file.jpg)
```

It really comes into its own when you want to extract many parameters, like the height, width, mean, standard deviation, colourspace, and the number of unique colours etc. all in one call:

```
read w h m s c u < <(identify -format "%w %h %[mean] %[standard-deviation] %[colorspace] %k" file.jpg)
```

Comment: Isn't `< <` a typo? bash 4.3.33 complains about it.

Comment: It should work fine. Did you copy and paste? There must be one spsce after first `<` and none after second `<`

Comment: Yes, I wrongly added one space instead of writing `< <(`. I've never seen this format!

Comment: It's called `process substitution` and is described here... http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html